# Why are these ways of choosing guests to a party the same?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You are having a party, and of your n friends you can invite only k guests. Why are the same number of guest lists as there are of ways of choosing whom not to invite?

Comment: Because if you decide whom not invite you immediately determine the number of those to be invited.

Comment: thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

As zoli said this is a intuitive result because choosing who is invited also gives who is not invited but you can show that mathematically because

n choose k = $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and

n choose n-k (those not invited) = $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-(n-k))!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Formally, there is a bijection between the set of possible guest lists and the set of possible exclude lists.

If your set of friends is $N$, and $K \subseteq N$ is an arbitrary guest list (of size $k$), then $N \setminus K$ is the exclude list.

Distinct guest lists correspond to distinct exclude lists, and distinct exclude lists correspond to distinct guest lists.